# GetDiskFreeSpaceExA Woes

Tags: c++, winapi, space, disk

I am not understanding something here. I am trying to use the [GetDiskFreeSpaceExA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getdiskfreespacea) function to get the drive space of a drive. When I run the following code:

```
// Setup the DWORD variables.
PULARGE_INTEGER lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller{},
    lpTotalNumberOfBytes{},
    lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes{};

// Lets construct the drive letter based on what the user passed.
/*std::string letter;
letter += driveLetter;
letter += ":\\";
letter += "\0";*/

if (GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(NULL, lpFreeBytesAvailableToCaller, lpTotalNumberOfBytes, lpTotalNumberOfFreeBytes)) {
    std::cout << lpTotalNumberOfBytes << "\n";
}
```

All I get back is "0000000000000000". I know there is something I am missing, can anyone shed some light on it?

Comment: `lpTotalNumberOfBytes` is a null pointer, you are printing its address (which is null, unsurprisingly). In general your way of calling the function is wrong, you don't have any memory where the result could be written to

Comment: It seems that you don't understand the difference between passing variables to a function [by value](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_value.htm), [by pointer](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_pointer.htm) and [by reference](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_function_call_by_reference.htm).

Answer (score 4):

You are passing *NULL pointers* to `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA()`, they don't point anywhere meaningful for it to write its output values to.

Declare local *non-pointer* variables, and pass them to `GetDiskFreeSpaceExA()` using the `&` address operator, eg:

```cpp
// Setup the DWORD variables.
ULARGE_INTEGER FreeBytesAvailableToCaller,
    TotalNumberOfBytes,
    TotalNumberOfFreeBytes;

// Lets construct the drive letter based on what the user passed.
/*std::string letter;
letter += driveLetter;
letter += ":\\";
letter += "\0";*/

if (GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(/*letter.c_str()*/NULL, &FreeBytesAvailableToCaller, &TotalNumberOfBytes, &TotalNumberOfFreeBytes)) {
    std::cout << TotalNumberOfBytes.QuadPart << "\n";
}
```

Alternatively,`GetDiskFreeSpaceExA()` lets you query just the values you actually want, you don't need to ask for all of them if you are not going to use all of them, eg:

```cpp
// Setup the DWORD variables.
ULARGE_INTEGER TotalNumberOfBytes;

// Lets construct the drive letter based on what the user passed.
/*std::string letter;
letter += driveLetter;
letter += ":\\";
letter += "\0";*/

if (GetDiskFreeSpaceExA(/*letter.c_str()*/NULL, NULL, &TotalNumberOfBytes, NULL)) {
    std::cout << TotalNumberOfBytes.QuadPart << "\n";
}
```

Comment: Ahhhh, I understand now. Thanks heaps :)

Answer (score 2):

`GetDiskFreeSpaceExA` does not allocate memory for its results.

You need to have `ULARGE_INTEGER` variables and pass pointers to it.